# Why not, first order logic to DNF conversion?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, binary

There seems to be [huge amount of discussion about converting "first order logic to CNF".](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=1st%20order%20logic%20to%20cnf)

But don't see much about "first order logic to DNF" conversion. What is the reason?

Comment: The procedure is very similar: given a way to convert a formula to CNF, very minor alterations give you a procedure for DNF.

Answer (score 3):

Both have their uses, and neither easier to convert to. DNF gives you the truth table of a formula: it shows you exactly which assignments of truth values to atomic formulas make the entire formula true. Converting a formula to CNF, and converting to DNF, are both [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness).

One reason why CNF gets more attention: the method of *resolution*, used in automated theorem-provers, requires conversion to CNF. Another: in complexity theory, one of the most famous and earliest NP-complete problems, [3-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#3-satisfiability), involves satisfiability of CNF formulas with at most 3 variables per clause. The dual problem of the *validity* of a formula, for which DNF is arguably better suited, clearly involves all assignments, and is co-NP-complete.